# Varargs в тайпскрипте

Tags: typescript

Хочу передавать в функцию произвольное число аргументов разных типов и использовать эти типы - [что-то вроде такого](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%250D%250Afunction%2520f%3CA%3E(a%253A%2520A)%253A%2520A%253B%250D%250Afunction%2520f%3CA%252C%2520B%3E(a%253A%2520A%252C%2520b%253A%2520B)%253A%2520A%2520%2526%2520B%253B%250D%250Afunction%2520f%3CA%252C%2520B%252C%2520C%3E(a%253A%2520A%252C%2520b%253A%2520B%252C%2520c%253A%2520C)%253A%2520A%2520%2526%2520B%2520%2526%2520C%253B%250D%250Afunction%2520f%3CA%252C%2520B%252C%2520C%252C%2520D%3E(a%253A%2520A%252C%2520b%253A%2520B%252C%2520c%253A%2520C%252C%2520d%253A%2520D)%253A%2520A%2520%2526%2520B%2520%2526%2520C%2520%2526%2520D%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Afunction%2520f(...args%253A%2520any%255B%255D)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520return%2520Object.assign(%257B%257D%252C%2520...args)%253B%250D%250A%257D%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520smth%2520%253D%2520f(%257B%2520x%253A%25201%2520%257D%252C%2520%257B%2520y%253A%25202%2520%257D%252C%2520%257B%2520z%253A%25203%2520%257D)%253B%250D%250Avar%2520res%2520%253D%2520smth.x%2520%252B%2520smth.y%2520%252B%2520smth.z%253B):

```
function f<A>(a: A): A;
function f<A, B>(a: A, b: B): A & B;
function f<A, B, C>(a: A, b: B, c: C): A & B & C;
function f<A, B, C, D>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D): A & B & C & D;

function f(...args: any[]) {
    return Object.assign({}, ...args);
}

var smth = f({ x: 1 }, { y: 2 }, { z: 3 });
var res = smth.x + smth.y + smth.z;
```

Поскольку мне нужно произвольное количество параметров, я бы хотел избавиться от

```
function f<A>(a: A): A;
function f<A, B>(a: A, b: B): A & B;
function f<A, B, C>(a: A, b: B, c: C): A & B & C;
function f<A, B, C, D>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D): A & B & C & D;
```

и заменить их единственным объявлением вроде:

```
function f<...T>(args: [...T]): &<...T>;
```

но этот вариант синтаксически некорректен.

Можно ли записать такое объявление?

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/50729287/4928642)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50729287/4928642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начиная с Typescript 3 можно сделать так:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

function f<T extends any[]>(...args: T): UnionToIntersection<T[number]> {
    return Object.assign({}, ...args)
}

var x = f({x: 3}, {y: 9}, {z: 13})
```

PS: `UnionToIntersection` взят [из этого ответа](//stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/4928642).